# Save multiple URL targets to text files

Tags: wget

I have a list of URLs and I want to save each of their targets in a separate text file.

Here's an example of the input file containing the URLs:

```
~$: head -3 url.txt 
http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P32234.txt
http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P05552.txt 
http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P07701.txt
```

I'm currently using a Python custom function to accomplish this task. It works, but the main inconvenient are: user has to copy-paste URLs manually (there's no direct file input) and the output contains some 'b' characters at the beginning of each line (?binary).

```
~$: head -3 P32234.txt
b' ID   128UP_DROME             Reviewed;         368 AA.
'b' AC   P32234; Q9V648;
'b' DT   01-OCT-1993, integrated into UniProtKB/Swiss-Prot.
```

Here's the Python code:

```
def html_to_txt(): 
    import urllib.request 
    url = str(input('Enter URL: ')) 
    page = urllib.request.urlopen(url) 
    with open(str(input('Enter filename: ')), "w") as f: 
        for x in page: 
            f.write(str(x).replace('\\n','\n')) 
    s= 'Done' 
    return s
```

Is there a cleaner way of doing this using some Unix utilities?

Comment: FYI, those `b'strings with a b prefix'` are [Python 3 bytes objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes). Such data should be written to a file opened in binary mode, and not converted to `str`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `-i` option:

```
wget -i ./url.txt
```

From `man wget`:

> -i file
>
> --input-file=file
>
> Read URLs from a local or external file. If - is specified as file, URLs are read from the standard input. (Use ./- to
> read from a file literally named -.) If this function is used, no URLs
> need be present on the command line. If there are URLs both on the
> command line and in an input file, those on the command lines will be
> the first ones to be retrieved. If --force-html is not specified, then
> file should consist of a series of URLs, one per line.
>
> However, if you specify --force-html, the document will be regarded as
> html. In that case you may have problems with relative links, which
> you can solve either by adding "" to the documents
> or by specifying --base=url on the command line.
>
> If the file is an external one, the document will be automatically
> treated as html if the Content-Type matches text/html. Furthermore,
> the file's location will be implicitly used as base href if none was
> specified.

Answer (score 5):

[`wget`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wget) has an option for doing exactly this:

```
wget --input-file url.txt
```

will read one URL per line out of `url.txt` and download them into the current directory sequentially.

More generally, you can use [`xargs`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs) for this sort of thing, combined with [`wget`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wget) or [`curl`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/curl):

```
xargs wget < url.txt
xargs curl -O < url.txt
```

`xargs` reads each line of its input and provides it as an argument to a command you give it. Here that command is `wget` or `curl -O`, both of which download a URL and save it into the current directory. `< url.txt` provides the contents of `url.txt` as the input to the `xargs` command.

---

The problem with your Python code is that what you get out of urllib is [byte](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes) data that you're then printing directly to a file, which stringifies the bytes to `b'abc\00\0a...'` (which is how you write byte literals).

Comment: `wget` also has the `-i (--input-file)` switch for this.

Comment: Good point! Edited.

Comment: @MichaelHomer: `xargs` solution is bad one since when it will call some `wget` process for many urls. Use `-i` option calls one wget process instead.

Answer (score 2):

I would do this in the shell with wget.

```
while read y; do
     wget "$y"
done < url.txt
```

Comment: The `cat file` in a for loop is discouraged. See `read` builtin. You'd want to use the file as input and iterate over the lines cointained within the file.

Answer (score 2):

with `w3m`:

```
echo 'http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148670/save-html-to-text-file' |
tee - - - | 
xargs -n1 w3m -dump | 
sed '/Save html/!d;N;N;N;N;N;N;N'
```

It seems to me that `xargs` shouldn't even be necessary - surely there's a setting for multiple urls at once, but I can't grok it at the moment. In any case, `xargs` works:

```
Save html to text file

            I'd like to save some (plain HTML) web pages to text file, from URL
            stored in text files as well.

            Here's an exemple of the input file containing the URLs:

            ~$: head -3 url.txt
Save html to text file

            I'd like to save some (plain HTML) web pages to text file, from URL
            stored in text files as well.

            Here's an exemple of the input file containing the URLs:

            ~$: head -3 url.txt
Save html to text file

            I'd like to save some (plain HTML) web pages to text file, from URL
            stored in text files as well.

            Here's an exemple of the input file containing the URLs:

            ~$: head -3 url.txt
Save html to text file

            I'd like to save some (plain HTML) web pages to text file, from URL
            stored in text files as well.

            Here's an exemple of the input file containing the URLs:

            ~$: head -3 url.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two other methods:

```
wget $(<file)
```

and

```
while read -r link; do wget "$link"; done < file
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would just keep the UniProt ACs in the file:

```
$ cat names
P32234
P05552
P07701
```

You can then use the same file for various operations. For example, to download the corresponding flat file from UniProt, feed it into a loop:

```
while read prot; do 
    wget http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/"$prot".txt -O "$prot".flat
done < names
```

Since your file now just has the accessions, you can re-use it to get, for example, the corresponding IDs:

```
$ while read prot; do  
    printf "%s\t" "$prot"
    wget http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/"$prot".txt -O - | 
        awk '$1=="ID"{print $2}'; 
 done 2>/dev/null < names 
P32234  128UP_DROME
P05552  ADF1_DROME
P07701  SGS5_DROME
```

Comment: That 's smart !